# Responsive Nav (Mobile Menu) Not working on some pages

Tags: jquery, css, html

Responsive navigation is working on home page but not working on [product page](http://www.tilescarreaux.com/300x450-glossy)

I have checked the code but couldn't find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rectify your product page code and change the css of body part.As I checked in iphone your home page menu code is not as other page. So if you modify your css then it may work for you.